# Ubuntu 13.10 Gnome - Nvidia 675mx and Intel drivers

Tags: drivers, gnome, 13.10, nvidia, nvidia-optimus

I've currently made a new switch over from 12.04 to 13.10 due to my love for the gnome 3 desktop and 12.04 were breaking Gnome 3 each time.
However 13.10 detects my Intel Ivy Bridge and will use it instead of my Nvidia, which is fair enough, however I have installed Nvidia-331 drivers with Optimus and installed Bumblebee UI in order to apply Nvidia to certain applications.

However back in my 12.04 I was able to play games like Left 4 Dead 2 with maxed out settings with a smooth and stable FPS, however now, Left 4 Dead 2 will jump with FPS spikes every second. Therefore pointing to the fact the Nvidia drivers might not be even activating!

I'm willing to start my driver installation from scratch and i've seen a lot of tutorials already out there, but am cautious of testing them out due to personal experience of graphics drivers being the end of my Ubuntu installation!

Question being has anybody got something close to this working? With smooth FPS in most gaming applications? If so please tell me how you did it!

Cheers
 
Raptus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried primus? 
According to
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/primus-better-performance-and-less.html
this should improve performance a little.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have installed primusrun and i've noticed a sizable difference in performance, however it's a little annoying having to call a command every time I want to run an application with primusrun? Is there a GUI available?

Comment: I don't know if there is a GUI for this, but in 14.04 daily which I'm using now you can simply switch graphics in your nvidia settings (http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1113424/img/nvidia-prime-profiles.jpg), changes then are applied after next login/restart. There is also prime-indicator which allows you to do this a little bit faster: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/prime-indicator-lets-you-quickly-switch.html. Unfortunately I can't help you with bumblebee, because I'm not using it anymore.

Comment: Ok I've tested the Primus Indicator on 13.10, it's meant for either 14.04 or 12.04 and if it hasn't been tested 13.10 as it states, it doesn't work on 13.10, it stopped it from booting, but luckily didn't break anything on a fundamental level. I've been able to add my games via Steam and I can put in primus parameters there, this would work fine for me. Thanks for your help :D